# How can I add jquery ui autocomplete to a dynamically created element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to get jQueryUI AutoComplete to trigger on dynamically created form input elements, but it's not working. I've tried using keyup.autocomplete and keydown.autocomplete as bind events in $.live(), but it's binding to the new elements - only those already on the page.

Try out the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6t74T/1/) (try typing "ava" in the first input, then click "Add an Input" and type the same in the new input).

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("input#addButton").click(function() {
        $("input.searchInput:last").clone(true).appendTo($(this).closest("form"));
        $("input.searchInput:last").val("");

    })

    $("input.searchInput").live("keydown.autocomplete", function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
                ],

            minLength: 2
        });
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
    <input id="addButton" name="addButton" type="button" value="Add an input" />
    <input name="search" value="" class="searchInput" maxlength="20" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just out curiosity, have you tried executing the binding each time a control is created for the specific object created? Good starting point for trouble shooting...

Comment: @Dutchie432: yes, I did - http://jsfiddle.net/6t74T/2/ - same result.

Comment: @Eric: Your fiddle (jsfiddle.net/6t74T/1) works for me in Chrome. I get autocomplete on the added box as well.

Comment: @MrChief: You're right... it works in IE8 too. Hmmm Must be an IE9 issue then....

Comment: This works in IE8 only when resetting the bind after the new input is created - jsfiddle.net/6t74T/2. The jsfiddle works, but not my actual code...

Comment: I think this has something to do with clone() - it doesn't seem to be copying the handlers - even when specifying withDataAndEvents AND deepWithDataAndEvents.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Function .live() is deprecated now.

Looks like code like this works:

```
var options = {
    source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript"],
    minLength: 2
};
var selector = 'input.searchInput';
$(document).on('keydown.autocomplete', selector, function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

Comment: changing accepted answer since this is compatible with new versions.

Comment: Thank you for this! Just helped me with a nested form fields issue in Rails 3.2 trying to get autocomplete working!

Comment: Hello @Andrei, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410824/autocomplete-in-jquery-with-dynamically-added-elements too pls. Thanks

Comment: Almost worked for me, I had to change `$(this).autocomplete(options);` to `$(this).autocomplete({source : options});` though.

Comment: Lifesaver! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

This works:

```js
$(function() {
  var options = {
    source: [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ],
    minLength: 2
  };

  $("input.searchInput").live("keydown.autocomplete", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
  });

  var addInput = function() {
    var inputHTML = " <input name='search' value='' class='searchInput' maxlength='20' />";
    $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");
    $("input.searchInput:last").focus();
  };

  if (!$("form#myForm").find("input.searchInput").length) {
    addInput();
  }

  $("input#addButton").click(addInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
  <input id="addButton" name="addButton" type="button" value="Add an input" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @Eric, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410824/autocomplete-in-jquery-with-dynamically-added-elements too pls. Thanks

Comment: Can you look at this questions do you have any solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693916/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-in-a-dynamic-form

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody still need, this code will trigger autocomplete when new created input get focus:

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input[name^=\'[new_element]\']', function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript"],
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```