# How can I add jquery ui autocomplete to a dynamically created element in jQuery 1.10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is nearly a verbatim post of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670918/how-can-i-add-jquery-ui-autocomplete-to-a-dynamically-created-element) question. However, once you flip over to jQuery 1.10, the code no longer works.

I did change the call to the "live" method, and switched it over to utilize the newer "on" method. 
What else do I need to do to fix this http://jsfiddle.net/sacredfaith/6t74T/458/ ?

```
$(function() {
var options = {
    source: [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ],
    minLength: 2
};

$(document.body).on("keydown.autocomplete", "input.searchInput",function(){
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});

var addInput = function() {
    var inputHTML = " <input name='search' value='' class='searchInput' maxlength='20' />";
    $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");        
    $("input.searchInput:last").focus();
};

if (!$("form#myForm").find("input.searchInput").length) {
    addInput();
}

$("input#addButton").click(addInput);
});
```

My searches thus far have yielded methods which use deprecated jquery libraries.
I'm needing a more updated version, but haven't been able to find success for the past several hours of working on this...

EDIT: Fiddle link and code updated to reflect "on" syntax changes. 
EDIT2: Thanks to all for your patience.

REFERENCE: For 1.10 solution see fiddle in comments of chosen answer, otherwise using 1.9, see fiddle in chosen answer directly.

Comment: you are not using delegation here, syntax is slightly different, check doc e.g equivalent to live() is: `$(document).on("focus","input.searchInput", function() {...});`

Comment: @sacredfaith: You can do this all in one line, without delegation. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't included [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/) library and also use it like this for dynamic elements

```
$(document.body).on('focus', 'input.searchInput' ,function(){
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6t74T/456/)**

Comment: So...there's no way to do this using jQuery 1.10?

Comment: You just have to include `jquery ui` even with `jQuery 1.10`. See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6t74T/457/)

Comment: I'm not too up-to-date with jQuery 1.10, but doesn't this create a new autocomplete widget each time an input is focused?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one line. Working **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/abUYEJOh/4/edit)**

```
 var addInput = function() {
    $("<input name='search' value='' class='searchInput' maxlength='20' />").appendTo("form#myForm").end().autocomplete(options).focus();
  };

if (!$("form#myForm").find("input.searchInput").length) {
    addInput();
}

$("input#addButton").click(addInput);
});
```

Comment: This is very similar to Tom's suggestion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Similar yes, but faster. You dont need to query the dom for the last input, the last input is already the one that is created and appended as a result of your addInput function. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete` creates a new widget, attached to the given element, so you only need to call it once per input, and not each time the key is pressed.  So you can drop that whole block of code, and just call `autocomplete` in your `addInput` function.

I've updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6rrs/3/) (also added jqueryUI JS and CSS)

```
var addInput = function() {
    var inputHTML = " <input name='search' value='' class='searchInput' maxlength='20' />";
    $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");        
    $("input.searchInput:last").autocomplete(options).focus();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('focus', "input.searchInput", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6t74T/459/

Comment: Sorry, your fiddle isn't working in my browser (Chrome Version 31)