# How to insert autocomplete jquery in innerhtml generated textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

The autocomplete jquery shows list of all users in the database, when atleast 2 characters are entered in the textbox. The autocomplete is working on a normal input field, but when genereated through innerHTML it is not working.

The autocomplete is working on the following field:-

```
<input type="text" id="j_d_permit_by[]" name="j_d_permit_by[]" >
```

A click on the button will add other fields as well calling the addjobdesc function:-

```
<img src="images/add.png" width="12" height="12"> <a href="javascript: addjobdesc();">Add New Job Description</a><br />
```

The function:-

```
     function addjobdesc() {
     var div = document.createElement('div');

        div.className = 'row';

        div.innerHTML = '<table id="tblObs" name="tblObs" width="70%"  bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><tr bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td colspan="5"><b>Job Description (Work Ppermit/ Activity)</b></td></tr>

<tr bgcolor="#33CC00">

    <td ><center> <b>Exact Location</b> </center></td> <td><b><center>Permit Initiated By<br />/<br />Activity Supervised by</center></b></td>

    <td><b><center>Permit Accepted By<br />/<br />aActivity Executor</center></b></td><td><b><center>For What Permit Issued</center></b></td>

    <td><b><center>Observation</center></b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><center><select name="s_area[]" id="s_area" onchange="addSubArea()">
    <option value="0">Chose Sub Area</option></select></center></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="j_d_permit_by_add" name="j_d_permit_by[]"></td>

    <td><center><select id="j_d_accept_by[]" name="j_d_accept_by[]" ><option value="0">Select User</option><?php  $users = getUserS(); 
    while($usersss = mysql_fetch_array($users)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $usersss[0];?>"><?php echo $usersss[4]." ".$usersss[5];  ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select></td>

    <td><center><textarea name="permit_ref[]" cols="30"> </textarea></center></td>

<td><center><textarea name="obs_permit[]" id="obs_permit" cols="30"></textarea></center></td></tr></table><input class="submit" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeR0ow__(this)">';

    <!--<input type="hidden" name="j_d_Location[]" id="j_d_Location" value="" /><input type="text" name="area_Location[]" id="area_Location" value="" readonly="readonly" />-->

    document.getElementById('job_desc').appendChild(div);

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#j_d_permit_by_add').autocomplete({
                    source: 'suggest_name.php',
                    minLength:2
                    });
            });

    var Max_Length = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('s_area[]').length)-1;
    document.getElementsByName('s_area[]').item(Max_Length).innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementsByName('s_area[]').item(Max_Length).innerHTML = document.getElementById('sarea_div').innerHTML;
    }
```

I want the autcomplete to work on the generated j_d_permit_by[] field in the innerHTML.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you write whole code please? for function addjobdesc..   OK

Comment: Edited in the question

Comment: input with id =j_d_permit_by_add is not available at jQuery(document).ready and hence the function is not bind to the input..

Comment: You need to bind the `autocomplete` again on newly created element like call this function `$('#newlyCreatedElementId').autocomplete({` in `addjobdesc()` function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bind the `autocomplete` in `jQuery(document).ready` but at that time there is no input exists with `id =j_d_permit_by_add` and hence the function is not bind to the input. You are generating the input dynamically so you have to bind `autocomplete` function in following way..

Try this to Bind the autocomplete function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('#j_d_permit_by_add', selector, function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: 'suggest_name.php',
            minLength:2
        });
    });
});
```

You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114244/1659563

@Guruprasad is also right, you can bind the `autocomplete` function after the input is generated dynamically in `function addjobdesc()`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand why it is not working. But even after implementing  your suggestion the autocomplete is still not working.

Comment: I have also tried to bind the autocomplete funciton again after 

document.getElementById('job_desc').appendChild(div);